# how to write syntax rule for string embed evaluate code

Tags: syntax, visual-studio-code, sublimetext, grammar, tmlanguage

i am try to write a vscode syntax file for custome language

**i am use photoshop draw the sample syntax for the custom language.**

[image: syntax-wxml]

how  to write the syntax of tmLanguage ?

### evaluate code rule

```
{
    "begin": "\\{\\{",
    "beginCaptures": {
        "0": {
            "name": "punctuation.definition.brace.curly.start"
        }
    },
    "end": "\\}\\}",
    "endCaptures": {
        "0": {
            "name": "punctuation.definition.brace.curly.end"
        }
    },
    "patterns": [
        {
            "include": "source.js#expression"
        }
    ]
}
```

use it for child string entity pattern but surround string can not match

### double quoted content rule for attribute of tag

```
{
    "begin": "\"",
    "beginCaptures": {
        "0": {
            "name": "punctuation.definition.string.begin.wxml"
        }
    },
    "end": "\"",
    "endCaptures": {
        "0": {
            "name": "punctuation.definition.string.end.wxml"
        }
    },
    "name": "string.quoted.double  <===============********||||",
    "patterns": [
        {
            "include": " the up pattern  ↑"
        }
    ]
}
```

if the  `name` is present，all double quoted content is string‘s color

else the surround string is plain text color.